# Backbone: do I need to change the update URL for Rails RESTful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have a simple model in Backbone.js with few configurations:

```
budget.Group = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: '/groups'
})
```

...now when I do something like this:

```
budget.Group.save({ id: 1, name: 'Food' });
```

... it attempts to PUT it to the following URL:

```
/groups
```

.. but my (Rails) app would post/put it to:

```
/groups/1
```

Do I need to configure my model to update to the correct url? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
var budget = new budget.Group({ id: 1, name: 'Food' });
budget.save();
```

Backbone will do the rest for you (and use the correct URL).

Answer (score 0):

As the two answers before mentioned you must instantiate your Model :

```
var budget = new budget.Group({ id: 1, name: 'Food' });
budget.save();
```

But you have also to change the `url` property to `urlRoot`

```
budget.Group = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/groups'
})
```

Comment: I see. The object is instantiated an sends the id to the URL but I never realized I need to use urlRoot for the correct URL. I'll try that out when I get home. Thanks for your help.